# Can't find right position on array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a table in my database and it has some columns like `time` and `text`... I want to have all entries existing in any columns in separate string arrays...

I'm sure that two string array correctly collect entries (using toast for test!) ...my first array is `texts` and second is `times`... I want to find **two last inserted text** according to inserting `time`... if I find two maximum `time`s in `times` array, using their position, I can find related text from `texts` array... here is my code:

```
        double maxtime = 0;
        double second_maxtime = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++) {

                if (Double.parseDouble(times[counter]) > maxtime) {
                    second_maxtime = maxtime;
                    maxtime = Double.parseDouble(times[counter]);
                } else if (Double.parseDouble(times[counter]) > second_maxtime &&           Double.parseDouble(times[counter]) != maxtime) {

                    second_maxtime = Double.parseDouble(times[counter]);
                }
         }

        long scndmxt= Math.round(second_maxtime);
        String scndmaxt = String.valueOf(scndmxt);
        int pos = Arrays.asList(times).indexOf(scndmaxt);

        long mxt = Math.round(maxtime);
        String maxt = String.valueOf(mxt);
        int pos1 = Arrays.asList(times).indexOf(maxt);

          String  last_text  = texts[pos];
          String  second_last_text = texts[pos1];
```

but when i try with toast to test it works correctly or not, it can find two last time correctly(`mxt` and `scndmxt`) ... but their position are not right... sometimes are `-1` and `0`.. and sometimes are `0` ad `1`...

i tried `int pos = Arrays.asList(otherArray).indexOf(...);` for other array and it works correctly...but here, I should convert strings to double for comparing ...  any help?!! thanks...

Comment: for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++) {
What is ' i ' ?

Comment: it's `dates.lengh`... i  think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First why are you using Double for timestamp you should use long instead.
Following code might help you

```
 long maxtime = 0;
 long second_maxtime = 0;
 int maxPos;
 int secondMaxPos;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < timestampArray.length; counter++) {

                if (Long.parseLong(times[counter]) > maxtime) {
                    second_maxtime = maxtime;
                    maxtime = Long.parseLong(times[counter]);
                    maxPos = counter;
                } else if (Long.parseLong(times[counter]) > second_maxtime &&           Long.parseLong(times[counter]) != maxtime) {

                    second_maxtime = Long.parseLong(times[counter]);
                    secondMaxPos = counter;
                }
         }

String  last_text  = texts[maxPos];
String  second_last_text = texts[secondMaxPos];
```